# CRM 4.0 - extracting contact data from email address

Tags: c#, asp.net, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm trying to use an email address to retrieve contact data.  I'm already using this but i'm wondering how to extend it so that custom fields can also be returned:

```
    public ContactInfo GetContactByEmail(string email, CrmService service)
    {
        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();

        query.EntityName = "contact";
        ColumnSet columns = new ColumnSet();
        columns.Attributes.Add("contactid");

        query.ColumnSet = columns;
        query.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
        query.Criteria.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And; 

        ConditionExpression condition = new ConditionExpression();
        condition.AttributeName = "emailaddress1";
        condition.Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal;
        condition.Values = new object[] { email.Trim() };
        query.Criteria.Conditions.Add(condition);

        RetrieveMultipleRequest request = new RetrieveMultipleRequest();
        request.Query = query;

        ContactInfo contactInfo = new ContactInfo();

        RetrieveMultipleResponse response = null;
        response = (RetrieveMultipleResponse)service.Execute(request);
        foreach (contact cont in response.BusinessEntityCollection.BusinessEntities)
        {
            contactInfo.contactid = cont.contactid.Value;

           //Would also like to retrieve a custom attribute called ContactType (type int)
        }

        return contactInfo;
    }
```

Any help or examples would be really appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add additional values to the `ColumnSet`, e.g.

```
ColumnSet columns = new ColumnSet();
columns.Attributes.Add("new_contacttype");
```

Note: The name here should be the schema and not the display.

Examples:

- [Using Dynamic Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151183.aspx).
- [Using the ColumnSet Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb928432.aspx).
- [CrmService.RetrieveMultiple Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb929002.aspx).